# AppleUSBEthernetHost kext with a signature validation error

Tags: macos, mac, kernel-extensions, big-sur, digital-signature

On macOS Big Sur (11.0.1), running `system_profiler SPExtensionsDataType` in terminal includes a kext named AppleUSBEthernetHost from an unknown developer that has a signature validation error:

It appears to maybe be an old version of a kext for which there is a newer version properly signed by Apple at a different path.

This kext very possibly existed before I upgraded to Big Sur.  I just looked at kexts now to ensure that I'm not running any unsupported legacy kexts.

Is it advisable / safe to remove the kext with the signature validation error?

What might have put it there?

What might have caused its signature error if it was once there without an error?

kext with signature validation error:

```
    AppleUSBEthernetHost:

      Version: 7.0
      Last Modified: 2019-07-18, 11:56 PM
      Bundle ID: com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost
      Notarized: No
      Loaded: No
      Obtained from: Unknown
      Kind: Intel
      Architectures: x86_64
      64-Bit (Intel): Yes
      Location: /Library/Apple/System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBEthernetHost.kext
      Kext Version: 7.0
      Loadable: No
      Signature Validation Errors: Kext signature validation error code -67050
      Dependencies: Satisfied
      Signed by: Unknown
```

Newer kext without errors, properly signed by Apple:

```
      Version: 8.1.1
      Last Modified: 2020-01-01, 3:00 AM
      Bundle ID: com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost
      Notarized: Yes
      Loaded: No
      Obtained from: Apple
      Kind: Universal
      Architectures: arm64e, x86_64
      64-Bit (Intel): Yes
      Location: /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBEthernetHost.kext
      Kext Version: 8.1.1
      Loadable: Yes
      Dependencies: Satisfied
      Signed by: Software Signing, Apple Code Signing Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
```